# NHibernate insert entity with proxy associations without fetching

Tags: performance, nhibernate, proxy

Let's say there are Category and Product tables. And Product **has assigned Id** and references Category:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public Product() {}
    public Product(int productId, string name, Category category) { ... }
}
```

When inserting three products like this:

```
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        Product product = new Product(1, "New Product", session.Load<Category>(1));
        session.Save(product);
        session.Flush();

        product = new Product(2, "New Product 2", session.Load<Category>(2));
        session.Save(product);
        session.Flush();

        product = new Product(3, "New Product 3", session.Load<Category>(3));
        session.Save(product);
        session.Flush();
```

It will only generate three inserts (it will not fetch categories).

But when doing the same set of actions without flushing after each insert, then it will fetch proxy associations:

```
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        Product product = new Product(1, "New Product", session.Load<Category>(1));
        session.Save(product);

        product = new Product(2, "New Product 2", session.Load<Category>(2));
        session.Save(product);

        product = new Product(3, "New Product 3", session.Load<Category>(3));
        session.Save(product);

        session.Flush();
```

The generated SQL is following:
[image: NHibernate fetching proxy associations on insert]

This is very simplified example, actually I need to insert about 1000 of entities and would like to use batching without fetching all related entities.

**UPDATE: complete example can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6H7K08_eEWiUHBjRExMUXVWSFU/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Using initializers instead the constructor to set the values has the same behavor?

Comment: Najera, yes, exactly same. Btw, I can share very basic sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Looks like Flush initiates sorting of inserted data. Documentation said this should improve performance with batch operations (http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/NHibernate/NHibernate/Environment/F/OrderInserts).
To avoid such behaviour add

```
x.SetProperty("order_inserts", "false");
```

to your NHibernate configuration.